# Java code style, immutable переменные

Tags: java, code-style

Есть пример кода:

```
//объявляем ссылку
SomeClass someClass;
//в зависимости от условий инициализируем ссылку тем или иным образом
if (condition1) {
  someClass = value1;
} else {
  someClass = value2;
}
```

Я столкнулся с мнением, что это "грязный код", и вместо этого надо стараться объявлять иммутабельные переменные везде, где это возможно:

```
final SomeClass someClass = someValue;
```

Чем плох первый пример и какие аргументы в пользу второго?

Comment: Вы можете сделать в первом примере кода `final SomeClass someClass;` и будет красиво.

Comment: Не уверен, что "иммутабельные переменные везде, где это возможно:" - это нормально, но код можно явно сократить, просто задав переменной какойе-то дефолтное значение, например `value2` и тогда достатчно будет потом написать только `if`  без всяких els'ов

Comment: `final SomeClass someClass = condition ? value1 : value2;`

Comment: Так и приходится писать с тернарником, но это не всегда подходит

Comment: Можно всего вынести в отдельный метод, вместо присваивания делать `return value1;` и `return value2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто добавьте модификатор `final` в вашем примере:

```java
final SomeClass someClass;
if (condition) {
  someClass = value1;
} else {
  someClass = value2;
}
```

Так сложнее в коде допустить ошибку и присвоить переменной что-нибудь не то. Считаю, что писать `final` — это хорошо.

В простых случаях, как уже подсказал @NowhereMan, пользуйтесь тернарным оператором:

```java
final SomeClass someClass = condition ? value1 : value2;
```

Если кода много, то, как предлагает @insolor, можно объявить новый метод:

```java
final SomeClass someClass = getSomeClass();
```

```java
private SomeClass getSomeClass() {
    if (condition) {
        return value1;
    } else {
        return value2;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, [компилируется](https://tio.run/##JYzBDoIwEETvfMUc6UESvRL/wYSj8bBCIYttId0twRi@vSKeZjLvZUZa6DR2r5xbRyK4xWmI5PEpgDk9HbcQJd1jmbiDJw5lo5HDcH@A4iDmUIGeAzlwUKz1MXCPUmOyBiuuONewTuzRL3@heYtaX01Jq3k/VBfK1fzQVmw5fwE).

Comment: Действительно, был не прав и узнал новое.